# How can I initialize PhantomData fields?

Tags: types, rust

I'm trying to use the Type State Pattern to implement a server mock but am getting lost in the syntax.
I have the following server code based on this tutorial for the Type State pattern:

```
/// Represents a PostgreSQL server.
pub struct Server<S: Messages> {
  marker: std::marker::PhantomData<S>,
  configuration: Configuration
}

/// Trait used to anchor message types.
pub trait Messages {}

/// Stopped server
pub enum Stopped {}
impl Messages for Stopped {}
impl Server<Stopped> {
  pub fn new(configuration: Configuration) -> Self {
    Server{configuration, marker: Stopped}
  }
}

/// Methods available to all messages
impl<S> Server<S> where S: Messages {}
```

Except I can't create the `new` method because I have no idea what to do about the `marker` property. Any ideas?

Comment: You can initialize it with `marker: Default::default()`, details:  https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html

Comment: Or just `marker: PhantomData` should work as well.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#unused-type-parameters

Comment: @ÖmerErden Turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PhantomData` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#impl-Default) `Default`, you can initialize it with:

```rust
Server {
    configuration,
    marker: Default::default(), 
    //marker: PhantomData::<Stopped> //or using explicit type 
    //marker: PhantomData // or sugar 
}
```

Since the marker field is not going to be used, you might want to define it as `_marker: Default:default()`.

---

***Trick that might help*** :

If you have multiple `Sized` generic parameters, you can use tuples instead of adding multiple marker fields:

```rust
pub struct Server<T, S, U, V> {
  _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<(T, S, U, V)>,
  configuration: Configuration
}
```

**Note :** Tuples only [implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html#impl-Default-65) `Default` if there are 12 or less elements inside, but this is not a problem in here since internal defaults will not be called ever. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3327556d7c85b4744367041e93e2ca20))

**See also:**

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html